# Is there any way to hide the the private IP address from a load balancer to the public? We failed a PCI scan due to this

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

We recently had a PCI scan and failed due to the scan being able to find and report what the private IP address was for our AWS classic ELB.

Is there a setting or something else I can do to prevent this address from being exposed?

I did verify that they did get the correct private IP address.

Here is the exact error the scan is reporting (replacing the DNS with xxx)-

```
IP Address:xxx.xxx.comHost:xxx.xxx.comPath:Threat Reference:More information on the Web Server Internal IP address available for the IIS web servers is
available at
[http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/1499] Bugtraq ID 1499.
Problem:Web Server Internal IP address available
07/02/08
CVE 2000-0649
CVE 2002-0419
Certain connections to web servers using commands such as GET, PROPFIND, or HEAD may reveal internal
IP addresses.
Impact:An attacker could determine information about your internal network structure from information
in http headers.
Resolution:For web servers other than IIS, contact the vendor.
```

Comment: What HTTP header was that in? It seems like your web server is adding that, it's not something the load balancer would be adding.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it!

The scan was failing on port 80. Port 80 on the load balancer listener was set to http. I changed the LB listener to TCP for port 80 and all works and it does not fail the scan. Now port 80 will not respond back with any header info.

FYI -
Port 443 on the load balancer is set for HTTPS and on the servers I have port 80 redirecting to HTTPS.

Thanks all for your input!!

Answer (score -1):

Some VPN or TOR Network setting can be used to hide the person's IP address.

Comment: That's the client IP, not the server IP. That's not relevant here.